# Make Load more Button disappear after fetching all data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

My code works fine, it displays more users when the load more button is clicked. 
my constraint right now is how to remove the Load more button if there is no more value on the response.

This is how my model looks like

```
 public function getFreeAds($page){
        $offset = 10*$page;
        $limit = 10;
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('escort');
        $this->db->where('status', 'Approved');
        $this->db->limit($offset ,$limit);
        $this->db->order_by("time_stamp, UPPER(time_stamp)", "DESC");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

My Controller looks like this

```
 public function getCountry(){
        $page =  $_GET['page'];
        $countries = $this->Home_model->getCountry($page);
        foreach($countries as $country){
            echo 
                 '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                     <div class="thumb">
                    <a ><div class="hover-effect" data-e_id="'.$country->e_id.'" id="profile2">
                    <div class="hover-content">
                    <h1> '.$country->ProfileName.'</em></h1>
                     <p> '.$country->Height.' CM tall '.$country->BreastCup.'  Breast Size <b>Nationality: '.$country->Nationality.' </b></p>
                     <button  type="button"  class="btn-info">View More</button>
                     <button  type="button"  class="'.$country->confirmstatus.'">'.$country->confirmstatus.'</button>
                     <div class="top">
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div></a>
                     <div class="image" width="70%" height="1000px">
                     <img src="uploads/'.$country->ProfilePicture.'">
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>';
        }
        exit;
    }
```

Here is my query code that displays the response.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        getcountry(0);

        $("#load_more").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).data('val');
            getcountry(page);

        });

    });

    var getcountry = function(page){
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>Home/getCountry",
            type:'GET',
            data: {page:page}
        }).done(function(response){
            $("#show_data").append(response);
            $("#loader").hide();
            $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
            scroll();
        });
    };

    var scroll  = function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#load_more').offset().top
        }, 1000);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get the next values in the same function and if there are values available you can make an input field(hidden) and then show or hide the button according to its value.

I'm writing a possible solution for your case, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. Remember there are better ways of doing this like using count but this is according to your code. See if it helps you.

**Controller**

```
public function getCountry(){

        $page       =  $_GET['page'];
        $countries  = $this->Home_model->getCountry($page);

        $nextValue  = $this->Home_model->getCountry($page+1); // get the values for the next page
        $showButton = !empty($nextValue) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // show the button if next value exists

        foreach($countries as $country){
            echo 
                 '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                     <div class="thumb">
                    <a ><div class="hover-effect" data-e_id="'.$country->e_id.'" id="profile2">
                    <div class="hover-content">
                    <h1> '.$country->ProfileName.'</em></h1>
                     <p> '.$country->Height.' CM tall '.$country->BreastCup.'  Breast Size <b>Nationality: '.$country->Nationality.' </b></p>

                     <input type="hidden" class="showButton" value="'.$showButton.'" /> 
                     <!-- make a hidden input field and assign a value (yes/no) -->

                     <button  type="button"  class="btn-info">View More</button>
                     <button  type="button"  class="'.$country->confirmstatus.'">'.$country->confirmstatus.'</button>
                     <div class="top">
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div></a>
                     <div class="image" width="70%" height="1000px">
                     <img src="uploads/'.$country->ProfilePicture.'">
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>';
        }
        exit;
    }
```

**View**

```
var getcountry = function(page){
    $("#loader").show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>Home/getCountry",
        type:'GET',
        data: {page:page}
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#show_data").append(response);
        $("#loader").hide();
        $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));

        // check the value of input field
        if($('.showButton:last').val() == "no"){

            $('#load_more').hide(); // hide the button
        }

        scroll();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I couldn't help but notice that it returns duplicate values. How can i ensure that it doesn't repeat any value from the database?

Comment: Umm.. what duplicate values? (where?). I haven't changed the logic at all so it shouldn't pose any new problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your response metadata with total pages count. During every request make count query to your DB with same clauses. In your JS code after every request compare current page with total pages from response and hide button if last page reached.